# Bootstrap 3 - Is it possible to have mixed input fields (default + horizontal)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to have different form input fields in the same form like this:

[image]

so that some part is default (label on top of the input field) and other part is horizontal (the label on the left side of the input field)

Comment: Sure..!You can use it anyway you want it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure. you can do whatever you want :) look at this:

```
<form>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="item1">Item 1:</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="item1" type="item1" placeholder="Enter text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="item2">Item 2:</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="item2" type="item2" placeholder="Enter text">
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px;">
      <div class="form-group" style="display: flex;">
        <label style="width: 80px; padding-top: 7px;" for="gross">Gross:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="item1" type="gross" placeholder="Enter text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" style="display: flex;">
        <label style="width: 80px; padding-top: 7px;" for="netto">Netto:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="item2" type="netto" placeholder="Enter text">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 73px; margin-top: 20px;" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

http://www.bootply.com/mPFpU6jyYe